# Convert point cloud to triangle mesh

Tags: matlab, opencv, graphics, computer-vision, vtk

I am trying to create triangle mesh from point cloud.
Maybe could anyone advice me something to make good triangulation ?

Comment: For point cloud, you should look at the [PCL library](http://pointclouds.org/). Looks like there is a tutorial for triangulation: [Fast triangulation of unordered point clouds](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/greedy_projection.php)

Comment: please use websearch for such general and  trivial things

Comment: VTK has some new classes to work with point clouds: https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/point-cloud